Window function & Overall Average
I am trying to get overall average number like this in each row. Can you help me how I can best achieve this using Snowflake SQL?
Overall Average should be (300+150+100)/3



ID
Desc
SUB_ID
Value
Average by ID
Overall Average




1
ABC
10
300
300
183.33


1
ABC
20
150
300
183.33


1
ABC
30
450
300
183.33


2
DEF
10
150
150
183.33


2
DEF
20
150
150
183.33


3
EFG
30
100
100
183.33


3
EFG
10
180
100
183.33


3
EFG
20
20
100
183.33



I was able to get Average by ID using window function AVG (Value) Over (partition by ID)

In SQL this can be done with window functions and OVER PARTITION
SELECT *
  , AVG (Value) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID]) AS [AverageByID]
  , AVG (Value) OVER() AS [OverallAverage]
FROM [data]


I need overall average by distinct ID not by number of records

Average of all values:
change the PARTITION BY to a constant like null or true
select 
    $1 AS id,
    $2 AS value,
    avg(value) over (partition by id) as avg_by_id,
    avg(value) over (partition by true) as overall_avg
from values 
    (1,300),
    (1,150),
    (1,450),
    (2,150),
    (2,150),
    (3,100),
    (3,180),
    (3,20);


Average Average:
You have asked for the average average, and this value is statically considered a rubbish value" so it is computable, but it's also generally meaningless. So should be avoided.
one one to do this is:
with example_data(id, value) as (
    select * from values
        (1,300),
        (1,150),
        (1,450),
        (2,150),
        (2,150),
        (3,100),
        (3,180),
        (3,20)
)
select a.* 
    ,b.*
from (
    select 
        id,
        value,
        avg(value) over (partition by id) as avg_by_id,
        avg(value) over (partition by true) as overall_avg_correct
    from example_data
) as a
cross join (        
    select avg(id_avg) as avg_avg
    from (
        select avg(value) as id_avg from example_data group by id
    )
) as b;


Or it can be done as a SELECT based sub-select:
select 
    id,
    value,
    avg(value) over (partition by id) as avg_by_id,
    avg(value) over (partition by true) as overall_avg_correct,
    (        
        select avg(id_avg)
        from (
            select avg(value) as id_avg from example_data group by id
        )
    ) as avg_avg
from example_data


What number would you think is valuable then vs average of average in this case, if I am looking for overall average by ID.

So, if I have various distinct IDs, would this work? Can you elaborate please how  over (partition by true) is taking into account count of distinct IDs to get the correct average,

partition by true is the same as antonio_mg's empty over() that are "all put into the same partition" BUT the key is, this window function is result is given for all results.

if you are wanting the mean (aka average) across a set of numbers, each number needs to have equal weighting. If you take the average of average, the result is not the mean of the number space. albeit, at some level via central limit theorem the numbers will converge. https://www.google.com/search?q=central+limit+theorem+average+of+averges
